# Amstock chart doesn't zoom on init event

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I need to zoom my chart to a specified period on `init` event.

```
      "listeners": [{
        "event": "zoomed",
        "method": this.calulateMetrics
      },{
        "event": "dataUpdated",
        "method": this.showPeriod
      }, {
        "event": "init",
        "method": this.showPeriod
      },{
        "event": "rendered",
        "method": this.showPeriod
      }],


  showPeriod(event) {
    // Retrieve the data
    let dates = this.$store.getters.getDates
    let startDate = dates[0]
    let endDate = (dates[dates.length - 1])
    endDate.setHours(22)
    try {
      this.chart.zoom(startDate, endDate)
      console.log("Last date", endDate)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("Error",(err.message))
    }
  },
```

Although I can't catch any errors the period remains the same.
Beside `init` I tried `rendered` and `dataUpdated` but it didn't help me either.

But when I trigger the call to external event `<v-btn v-on:click="showPeriod">Button</v-btn>` it works fine.

The whole options file is following:

```
   this.chart = window.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "path": AmCharts_path,
      "type": "stock",
      "theme": "light",

      "dataSets": this.$store.state.portfoliosData.performance.map(function (port, idx) {
        return {
          "title": port.name,
          "fieldMappings": [{
            "fromField": "value",
            "toField": "value"
          }],
          "dataProvider": port.data,
          "compared": (idx === 0 ? false : true),
          "categoryField": "date"
        }
      }),

      "panels": [{
        "title": "Value",
        "percentHeight": 70,
        "stockGraphs": [
          {
            "id": "g1",
            "valueField": "value",
            "comparable": true,
            "compareField": "value",
            "balloonFunction": this.ballonRender,
            "compareGraphBalloonFunction": this.ballonRender
          }]
      }],

      "chartScrollbarSettings": {
        "graph": "g1",
        "markPeriodChange": true
      },

      "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
      },

      "categoryAxesSettings": {
        "groupToPeriods": ["DD"]
      },

      "balloon": {
          "fixedPosition": true,
          "maxWidth": 10000,
          "offsetY": 1,
      },

      "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",

      "chartCursorSettings": {
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": true,
        "selectWithoutZooming": true,
        "showNextAvailable": true,
        "categoryBalloonAlpha": 0.8,
        "bulletsEnabled": true,
        "bulletSize": 10,
        "valueZoomable":true,
        "usePeriod": "DD",
        "categoryBalloonDateFormats": [
            {period:'fff',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
            {period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
            {period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
            {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
            {period:'DD',format:'EEEE, MMM DD'},
            {period:'WW',format:'EEEE, MMM DD'},
            {period:'MM',format:'MMM'},
            {period:'YYYY',format:'YYYY'}
          ]
      },

       "periodSelector": {
         "position": "bottom"
      },
    });
  },
```

Reproduction link can be find [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jz98r2x3o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that AmCharts' listener callbacks don't understand your component scope. `this` in the callbacks refers to AmCharts' callback scope, not your component. Every AmCharts listener provides a reference to itself in the event's `chart` property (see [`init`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#init), for example), so changing all of your `this.chart` lines to `event.chart` in your callbacks will fix that part of the problem. If you need a reference to your component itself, add a custom property to the chart object in your `renderGraph()` method then refer to that through `event.chart`:

```
  renderGraph() {
    // ...
    this.chart = window.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      // ...
      componentRef: this,
      // ...
    })
  }

  //example using initPeriod:
  initPeriod(event) { //event parameter contains {type: "init", chart: stockChartReference}
    console.log("init period")
    let dates = event.chart.componentRef.$store.getters.getDates
    let startDate = dates[0]
    let endDate = (dates[dates.length - 1])
    endDate.setHours(22)
    try {
      event.chart.zoom(startDate, endDate)
      console.log("Last date", endDate)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("Error",(err.message))
    }
  },
```

Your `zoomed` listener is refering to an undefined method called `calulateMetrics`. I see a method called `calculateMetrics` in amstore but I'm not sure if that's what you meant and changing it to that doesn't seem to work for me, so I defer to you on adding the appropriate method. Adding that missing method along with making sure that you refer to the chart object correctly like the other callbacks will fix your problem.

Demo for everything except `zoomed` due to the missing method: https://codesandbox.io/s/5wpopzwlnp

Comment: Thanks! Great feature of `Amcharts`

Comment: is there a way how can I perform a `chartCursor` `showCursorAt(category)` in `initPeriod`?
Looks like I can to it only in the `chartCursor` event scope. However I can be wrong. Because `event.chart.chartCursor. showCursorAt()' doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667781/amcharts-chartscrollbar-is-undefined-in-event-callback