# Amcharts: chartScrollbar is undefined in event callback

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I want to replicate the [following](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/2466eefebdfecfcc77a0b2b17cb3efd4) example.

When I try to access the chartBoard property I receive an error that this object is `undefined`.

```
  rendereMethod(e) {
    console.log("rendered")
    var sb = e.chart.chartScrollbar.set.node;
    sb.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      e.chart.mouseIsDown = true;
    });
    e.chart.chartDiv.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
      e.chart.mouseIsDown = false;
      // zoomed finished
      console.log("zoom finished", e.chart.lastZoomed);
    });
  },
```

That is weird because `chartScrollbar` doesn't have any events or methods according to docs.

This is the options of my graph

```
    this.chart = window.AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "path": AmCharts_path,
      "type": "stock",
      "theme": "light",
      "componentRef": this,
      "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,

      "dataSets": this.$store.state.portfoliosData.performance.map(function (port, idx) {
        return {
          "title": port.name,
          "fieldMappings": [{
            "fromField": "value",
            "toField": "value"
          }],
          "dataProvider": port.data,
          "compared": (idx === 0 ? false : true),
          "categoryField": "date"
        }
      }),

      "panels": [{
        "title": "Value",
        "percentHeight": 70,
        "componentRef": this,
        "stockGraphs": [
          {
            "id": "g1",
            "valueField": "value",
            "comparable": true,
            "compareField": "value",
            "balloonFunction": this.ballonRender,
            "compareGraphBalloonFunction": this.ballonRender
          }],
      }],

      "chartScrollbarSettings": {
        "markPeriodChange": true,
        "usePeriod": "DD",
        "autoGridCount": true,
        "graph": "g1",
        "scrollbarHeight": 40
      },

      "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
      },

      "categoryAxesSettings": {
        "groupToPeriods": ["DD"]
      },

      "balloon": {
          "fixedPosition": true,
          "maxWidth": 10000,
          "offsetY": 1,
      },

      "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",

      "chartCursorSettings": {
        "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
        "categoryBalloonEnabled": true,
        "selectWithoutZooming": true,
        "showNextAvailable": true,
        "categoryBalloonAlpha": 0.8,
        "bulletsEnabled": true,
        "bulletSize": 10,
        "valueZoomable":true,
        "usePeriod": "DD",
        "categoryBalloonDateFormats": [
            {period:'fff',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
            {period:'ss',format:'JJ:NN:SS'},
            {period:'mm',format:'JJ:NN'},
            {period:'hh',format:'JJ:NN'},
            {period:'DD',format:'EEEE, MMM DD'},
            {period:'WW',format:'EEEE, MMM DD'},
            {period:'MM',format:'MMM'},
            {period:'YYYY',format:'YYYY'}
          ]
      },

      "listeners": [
        {
          "event": "zoomed",
          "method": this.calulateMetrics
        },
        {
          "event": "init",
          "method": this.initPeriod
        },
        {
          "event": "rendered",
          "method": this.rendereMethod
        }
      ],

       "periodSelector": {
         "position": "bottom"
      },
    });
```

Reproduction code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jz98r2x3o)

Although the example code is for serial graphs, I guess it should be fine for `stock` as well

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's the point of trying to apply this workaround when stock charts only fires the zoomed event when using the scrollbar once due to `updateOnReleaseOnly` being set to true by default, which hasn't been changed in your config. The workaround was developed for serial charts, which have this setting set to false by default. If you actually had `updateOnReleaseOnly` set to false, then trying to do this would make sense.

Comment: If you *really* need this workaround for reasons that aren't obvious, use a query selector instead as the stock chart has a much different structure than a serial chart `e.chart.div.querySelector('.amcharts-scrollbar-chart-div')`. See it in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6rc8y00/68/)

Comment: @xorspark Take a look on this question, please https://stackoverflow.com/q/51654409/3911211 I'm sure I try to make a workaround because have no idea how to it in a proper way. My idea is to listen to mouse event and update zoom to the nearest rounded date.